# Inconsistent accessibility: property type ' ' is less accessible than property' '

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a contact managers program using a list to store and display the data. I need to view a report that displays a summary of contacts available and then have a menu to allow the user to interact with the program. I have a method to create a list with data and a method to create a new contact but my contact class and createcontact method keeps getting the error:
Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'Contact.ContactTypes' is less accessible than property 'Contact.GetContactType'. I am not sure how to fix this

Any guidance would be appreciated

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{         
    //Declare the list

    List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

    //Main Driver
    char menuItem;
     Console.WriteLine("Contact List\n");
    menuItem = GetMenuItem();
    while (menuItem != 'Q')
    {

        ProcessMenuItem(menuItem, contactList);
        menuItem = GetMenuItem();

    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, goodbye");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
//Returns either a 'C', 'R', 'U', 'D', 'L', or 'X' to the caller
static char GetMenuItem()
{
    char menuItem;
    DisplayMenu();
    menuItem = char.ToUpper(IOConsole.GetChar("\nPlease pick an item: "));
    while (menuItem != 'C'
        && menuItem != 'R' && menuItem != 'Q' && menuItem != 'U' && menuItem != 'D' && menuItem != 'S' && menuItem != 'L' && menuItem != 'F' && menuItem != 'P' && menuItem != 'T')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nError - Invalid menu item");
        DisplayMenu();
        menuItem = char.ToUpper(IOConsole.GetChar("\nEnter option or M for menu:"));
    }
    return menuItem;
}

static void DisplayMenu()
{
   Console.WriteLine("C-> Create Contacts");
   Console.WriteLine("R-> Remove Contacts");
   Console.WriteLine("U-> Update Contacts");
   Console.WriteLine("D -> Load data from file");
   Console.WriteLine("S-> Save data to file");
   Console.WriteLine("L-> View sorted by last name");
   Console.WriteLine("F-> View sorted by first name");
   Console.WriteLine("P-> View by partial name search");
   Console.WriteLine("T-> View by contact type");
   Console.WriteLine("Q-> Quit");
}

//Routes to the appropriate process routine based on the user menu choice
static void ProcessMenuItem(Char menuItem, List<Contact> contactList)
{
    switch (menuItem)
    {
        case 'C':
            createContact();
            break;
        case 'R':
            Console.WriteLine("enter the contact name To delete");
            removeContact(contactList, Console.Read().ToString() );
                break;
        case 'U':
            updateContact(contactList);
            break;
        case 'D':
            LoadFromFile();
            break;
        case 'S':
            saveToFile();
            break;

        case 'L':
            sortByLastName(contactList);
            break;
        case 'F':
            sortByFirstName(contactList);
               break;
        case 'P':
               DisplayList(contactList);
               break;
        case 'T':
               sortByContactType();
               break;
        case 'Q':

               break;

    }                   
}

 public static void createContact()
{
    Contact c1 = new Contact();
    try { 
    Console.WriteLine("\nGetFirstName");
    c1.GetFirstName =  Console.ReadLine();
        }
    catch (System.NullReferenceException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Contact create failed");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nGetLastName");
    c1.GetLastName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("\nGetEmailAddress");
    c1.GetEmailAddress = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("\nGetPhoneNumber");
    c1.GetPhoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("\nContactTypes");
     //ERROR LINE//
    c1.GetContactType = (ContactTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(ContactTypes), Console.ReadLine(), true);

    //Create more contacts...

    //Add all contacts here
    ContactCollection contactList = new ContactCollection();
    contactList.Add(c1);

    //Loop through list
    foreach (Contact c in contactList)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(c.GetFirstName);
        Console.WriteLine(c.GetLastName);
        Console.WriteLine(c.GetEmailAddress);
        Console.WriteLine(c.GetPhoneNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(c.ContactTypes);

    }

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

> Here is my contact class

```
class Contact
{

    //private member variables
    private String _firstName;
    private String _lastName;
    private ContactTypes _contactTypes;
    private String _phoneNumber;
    private String _emailAddress;




    //Public constructor that takes five arguments
    public Contact()
    {
        //Call the appropriate setter (e.g. FirstName) to set the member variable value
        /*GetFirstName = firstName;
        GetLastName = lastName;
        ContactTypes = contactTypes;
        GetPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        GetEmailAddress = emailAddress;*/

    }


    /*********************************************************************
     * Public accessors used to get and set private member variable values
     *********************************************************************/
    //Public  ContactTypes accessor
        public ContactTypes GetContactType
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _contactTypes;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == null)
       {
                throw new Exception("ContactType must have a value");
       }
            else
       {
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _contactTypes = value;
       }
        }
    } 
    enum ContactTypes { Family, Friend, Professional }
    //Public FirstName accessor: Pascal casing
    public String GetFirstName
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
            {
                throw new Exception("First name must have a value");
            }
            else
            {
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _firstName = value;
            }
        }
    }

    //Public LastName accessor: Pascal casing
    public String GetLastName
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
                throw new Exception("Last name must have a value");
            else
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _lastName = value;
        }
    }



    //Public PhoneNumber accessor
    public String GetPhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            /*bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(value, @"/d{3}-/d{3}-/d{4}");
            if (!isValid)
            {
                throw new Exception("PhoneNumber must have a value");
            }
            else
            {
                _phoneNumber = value;
            }*/
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
            {
                throw new Exception("PhoneNumber must have a value");
            }
            else
            {
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _phoneNumber = value;
            }
        }
    }



    //Public Email accessor
    public String GetEmailAddress
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _emailAddress;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
            {
                throw new Exception("EmailAddress must have a value");
            }
            else
            {
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _emailAddress = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `enum ContactTypes` should be marked public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set contactType enum to be public, that might fix the issue

```
    public enum ContactTypes { Family, Friend, Professional }
```